# Function call does not change value

Tags: python

```
def divide_by_2(number):
   number /= 2

...

def main():
    n = 42
    divide_by_2(n)
    print(n)
```

The result is 42, not 21. Why is this the case? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Variables don't work like that in python: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 3):

You have to return the value from your function

```
def divide_by_2(number):
   return number / 2 # return the calculation


...

def main(n):
    n = divide_by_2(n)
    print(n)
    >> 21

main(42) # call main with variable number
```